# When to use bcadd vs normal addition of floats

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pulling values from a MySQL database where the column has the type `decimal(10,2)` so values are already stored with two decimal places (I'm rounding the value before storing, so `12.346` would be stored as `12.35` which is what I want.)

Those values being pulled from the DB are later being used for some basic math:

```
$val1 = (float) $val1_from_db; // 12.35
$val2 = (float) $val2_from_db; // 2.51
$val3 = (float) $val3_from_db; // 11.77
```

In PHP im doing a simple addition of `$val1 + $val2 + $val3;` and getting the correct value needed `26.63`

I'm wondering if this is perfectly fine or if I should be using [bcadd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php)

Comment: I've been trying to find a concrete example of floating point error in PHP (I'm really curious about the subject). My research so far has only shown that floating point errors become relevant when you fail to round properly on display (e.g. print raw float variables as in `echo $val1;`) or you accumulate tons of raw calculations (several million). It never hurts to handle money as integers or strings, but I suspect it's overkill for almost everything else. (An [example](https://3v4l.org/rlEun) of what I mean)